# zsh command not found [ nvm command not found after install successfully in macOs ]

Tags: macos, homebrew, nvm

```
brew install nvm
```

I am installed successfully NVM in my macOs. But also then after I got NVM command not found error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstall nvm again.

```
brew reinstall nvm
```

create the .zshrc file.

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

Paste code which I am write here

```
# NVM Akash Stuff
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
. "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"
```

Comment: Is `export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"` necessary ? I'd thought that's the default directory for nvm.

Comment: yes, that's necessary. Try and you will get the solutions.

Comment: How is this even working??? opt directory does not exist